# Bring to front and glow with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

**EDIT:** After writing my question, it has occurred to me that the `toFront()` code probably recreates the element in a different position in the DOM. When it removes the element first, it probably loses any events attached for IE and Opera, hence my problem. I will work on a delegated event alternative but still open to suggestions.

---

I have shapes in a Raphael paper that are suppose to glow when you hover over them. However, since these shapes are position directly next to each other, to make sure you see the glow all the way around I have to bring the current shape to the front.

This the current element is on top, so it's glow will appear over the top of adjacent shapes. My code works fine in Webkit and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Opera or IE.

Once I added in the bring to front code, the mouseout event never trigger when it should in Opera/IE.

Please see [my example on JS Fiddle which is broken for Opera/IE](http://jsfiddle.net/YrpXJ/2/). If you comment out the `toFront()` line, it will trigger the mouseout event as expected in all browsers.

*In that example - since the mouseout nevers get trigger, ergo the glow remains - multiple glows build up per shape. I can fix this by checking for the glow before adding it but this doesn't fix the problem.*

**EDIT 2:** So I've come up with [a solution that uses single variable to store the glow object](http://jsfiddle.net/uyscK/) which seems to fix the problem. Interestingly enough though, a mouseout event on the containing div doesn't actually get called in Opera (haven't checked IE). Awww man, so close :(

Comment: if you use jquery too, you can use `.live` if that is indeed the case (recreating). alternatively, does modifying the z-index work (instead of calling toFront)?

Comment: I've already tried z-index and it doesn't work in SVG. jQuery `.live()` is deprecated as of v1.7 so I'm trying `.on()` but haven't finished refactoring yet.

Comment: @Mark [Delegating events](http://jsfiddle.net/YrpXJ/3/) doesn't solve it either, I have another idea I might try.

Comment: @Mark My other idea sort of worked (See Edit 2 in my Q). Looking into alternative ways to trigger a paper-wide mouseout now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me in Opera, haven't tried in IE but it should work:

```
paper.forEach(function(element) {
    element.hover(function() {
       if (!glow) {
           this.toFront();
           glow = this.glow({ color: "#555", width: 10 });
       }
    },
    function(){
       glow.remove();
       glow = false;        
    }             
);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76bjf/

Comment: Wow that actually works :s My [similar solution](http://jsfiddle.net/uyscK/) didn't work for me, I still had issues with the mouseout event. Thanks.